# php select from mysql where title begins with A (and A alone)

Tags: php, mysql, select, alphabetical

I'm sure this is super easy, but can't seem to figure it out.. I need to select all titles from my database where the title starts with A, or B, or C etc. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM weblinks WHERE catid = 4 AND title LIKE 'A'
```

but returns nothing.. Could someone help me out with this?

Cheers

Comment: I also forgot to ask how to do it if the title begins with a number..

Comment: And how to do this with PDO?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

For titles starting in 'A' use a `%` after the `A`

```
SELECT * FROM weblinks WHERE catid = 4 AND title LIKE 'A%'
```

For titles with the letter 'A' in it, use `%` on either side of `A`

```
SELECT * FROM weblinks WHERE catid = 4 AND title LIKE '%A%'
```

For titles ending in the letter 'A', use `%` before the `A`

```
SELECT * FROM weblinks WHERE catid = 4 AND title LIKE '%A'
```

Basically `%` is a wildcard. It tells MySQL that anything can be in the location.

For having numbers as the first letter, check out [Mark's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069186/php-select-from-mysql-where-title-begins-with-a-and-a-alone/2069273#2069273)

Comment: I think second example is supposed to end in `'%A%'`

Comment: Thanks muchly, I also forgot to ask how to do it if the title begins with a number?

Comment: Replace the Letter `A` with a Number like `1%`.

Comment: can it be done where it's a number wildcard, like it could be any number?

Comment: Then you start getting into MySQL Regex's. You might want to ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 7):

The wildcards for `LIKE` are `%` and `_`, where % matches 0 or more characters and _ matches exactly one character.

Answer (score 7):

The existing answers are correct for beginning with A:

```
SELECT * FROM weblinks WHERE catid = 4 AND title LIKE 'A%'
```

For beginning with any number you can use the REGEXP operator:

```
SELECT * FROM weblinks WHERE catid = 4 AND title REGEXP '^[0-9]'
```

Comment: Come to steal the accepted answer away from me eh? (Just Kidding) Added a link to your answer.

Comment: @Soulie: you should probably accept Chacha's answer since you changed the question after he had already answered it correctly. Next time, if you make a substantial change to a question, start a new question rather than changing an existing one.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
SELECT * FROM weblinks WHERE catid = 4 AND ((title like 'A%') OR (title like 'B%'))
```

so on and so forth

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM weblinks WHERE catid = 4 AND title LIKE 'A%'`

% tells "anything", so it's "A" then anything. Only works with the LIKE comparison operator.